# Examples SQL statement queries for data warehouse in oracle database

Tags: java, sql, mdx, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am asking for example SQL queries for data warehouse in an oracle database or star schema, then  embed  in JAVA application. I want an example, that can show the data in dimensional format like using MDX of Microsoft Analysis

```
Region     Town              Amount
 Region1
           Town1           4000
           Town6           3500

Region2   Town3           7819
          Town7           9000
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can search it on google :** (keyword : oracle pl sql example )

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/a_samps.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/a_samps.htm

Comment: I want an example , that can show the data in dimensional format like using MDX of Microsoft Analysis. Thank you